# Having problems with Get and set method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter

I'm having problems with get method from an array.

```
public class Person 
{



    private String navn; 
    private int personNummer;
    private int alder;

    public Person (String navn, int personNummer, int alder)
    {
        this.navn = navn;
        this.personNummer = personNummer;
        this.alder = alder;

        }
       public static String getName(Person a){
            return a.navn;        


       }  
    }


    public class Kunderegister {
        private Scanner input;
        private Person [] brukere;
    int i = 0;

    public Kunderegister () 
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        brukere = new Person [20];
    }
    public void leggTilBruker()
    {
     System.out.println("give the name"); 
        System.out.println("Give name");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Give age");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Give number");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        Person a = new Person(name,number,age);
        brukere[i]=a;
        i++;

    }
    public void visPersonListe()
    {
      for (int j = 0; j > 20; j++){
            System.out.println(Person.getName(brukere[0]));

        }
    }
```

So when i'm running this code it has no build errors, but it does not print out the name of the customer. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to pass `Person` object to the getter, the information you need is already there. Simply `return this.navn;`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun He is trying to write a static method, apparently.  `this.navn` will not work.  Whether this is good style or not is a separate question.

Comment: The "normal" style is to define a `get` method that is not `static`, usually takes no parameters, and returns `this.<something>`.  Then you call it with `object.getData()` instead of `ObjectClass.getData(object)`.  The way you did it should work fine, but it is a very unusual style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A getter should not be static. I made some modifications. This should work:

```
public class Person  
{ 
    private String navn; 
    private int personNummer;
    private int alder;

    public Person (String navn, int personNummer, int alder)
    { 
        this.navn = navn;
        this.personNummer = personNummer;
        this.alder = alder;
    } 

    public String getName() {
        return this.navn;        
    }   
}

public class Kunderegister { 
    private Scanner input;
    private Person [] brukere;
    int i = 0;

    public Kunderegister ()  
    { 
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        brukere = new Person [20];
    } 

    public void leggTilBruker() 
    { 
        System.out.println("give the name"); 
        System.out.println("Give name");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Give age");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Give number");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        Person a = new Person(name,number,age);
        brukere[i]=a;
        i++;
    } 

    public void visPersonListe() 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < brukere.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(brukere[j].getName());
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your loop condition is

```
for (int j = 0; j > 20; j++){
    System.out.println(Person.getName(brukere[0]));
```

Change the `j > 20` to `j < 20` condition in the loop and also, the index of `brukere[0]` to `brukere[j]`.

Also

> You don't need to pass Person object to the getter, the information
>   you need is already there. Simply return Person.getName(brukere[j]);

Change it as below or something similar :-

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
    System.out.println(Person.getName(brukere[j]));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake by me. no idea how i didnt see that

Comment: I will, it just has a timer so need to wait 5 more mins

Comment: `this.getName` will not work because there is no `getName` defined for `Kunderegister`.  You probably got taken in by the sloppy indentation.